# File upload in case of publicly hosted Apache Tomcat issue

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading a file to Amazon S3 using Java Servlet. I have a simple JSP web form that has a textbox and a submit button. I am entering the filepath in the textbox and when I click submit button it calls the servlet. This servlet has a java code to upload the file to Amazon S3.

Case 1: Apache Tomcat on localhost (Installed using Eclipse IDE)
This works smoothly. If I give the filepath /home/Videos/sample.avi. The file gets uploaded to Amazon S3.

Case 2:Apache Tomcat hosted on Amazon EC2 instance that has a public IP. 
After hosting the project publicly, when I hit the url from any client computer, it displays the textbox and the submit button. I enter a filepath for the file present on the client computer and click submit. Now the Apache Tomcat container searches for the file on the machine where it is hosted and hence it fails becuase no such file is present there. I verified this issue by manually keeping the file on the same path on hosted server where the file is present on the localpath of my local computer..it works in then.

So how do we handle file upload scenarios in publicly hosted servers?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String filepath = request.getParameter("filepath");
    String metaData = request.getParameter("metaData");
    uploadFileName = filepath;



    if ((!filepath.endsWith(".mp4")) && (!filepath.endsWith(".avi"))
            && (!filepath.endsWith(".avi"))
            && (!filepath.endsWith(".mpeg"))) {
        out.println("alert('Not a valid file format')");
    } else {

        String amazonURLToRecording = "http://d33tbzutgyvlht.cloudfront.net/";
        keyName= bucketName + Math.random();

        try {
            System.out
                    .println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
            File file = new File(uploadFileName);


            if(!s3Client.doesBucketExist(bucketName)){
                CreateBucketRequest cbr=new CreateBucketRequest(bucketName);
                s3Client.createBucket(cbr);

            }
            Thread.sleep(30000);
            //waitForBucketToBeCreated(bucketName);
            PutObjectRequest putObject = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file);
            putObject.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
            ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
            meta.setContentType("application/octet-stream"); // binary // data

            putObject.setMetadata(meta);
            s3Client.putObject(putObject);

            System.out.println("Video was successfully uploaded.");


        } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
            System.out
                    .println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which "
                            + "means your request made it "
                            + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response"
                            + " for some reason.");
            System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
            System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
            System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which "
                    + "means the client encountered "
                    + "an internal error while trying to "
                    + "communicate with S3, "
                    + "such as not being able to access the network.");
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you handle file upload requests in your servlet? Can you post the code?

Comment: String filepath=request.getParameter("filepath");                          File file = new File(filepath);
PutObjectRequest putObject = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file);
    putObject.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
    ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
    meta.setContentType("application/octet-stream"); // binary // data
    
putObject.setMetadata(meta);
    s3Client.putObject(putObject);    
  
Do I need to copy the file to a folder on the public server?

Comment: What is the next line of code?

Comment: Andrey:I have uploaded the code. Do I need to write another code for copying the file to a particular folder on the server?

Comment: Thanks! Added a comment. You will need to update your servlet and JSP page, or whatever technology you use on UI.

Answer (score 1):

You should send the file contents from the client to the server. The file path is not enough. The EC2 server does not know about the file, the file location from the servlet request is irrelevant. The code worked on localhost, because both, client and server shared the same filesystem.

Have a look at this guide: [Uploading Files with Java Servlet Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glrbb.html)